# can we modify java class code (POJO) automatically at runtime?

Tags: java, web-services

We are doing automation of rest api's using core Java. we are fetching values from db ,setting the values into pojo, creating json request. After that we are calling endpoint url using HttpConnection. Sometimes request is modified at server side,so we need to manually do changes in our pojo class after that only we can hit the request. Is there any way to add or remove some variables from/to java class at runtime automatically.

Comment: That sounds like what we do on a daily basis (calling getters/setters on objects is setting values programmatically). If you mean to do that dynamically, then try java reflection

Comment: And to be clear: you can't change the static structure of classes (easily). There are tools for hot swapping code, but that is a mechanism to debug / develop. It is a rather odd idea to do something like that for testing. If your server changes data, and objects are no longer equal, then you should probably look in how your equals methods are designed.

Comment: You could try use a dynamic structure like a map instead of a pojo.